# How to remove backend address pool configuration from load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have used Az-powershell task in azure devops pipeline and tried below cmdlet.Its showing error " Set_AzLoadBalancer: Resource/Subscription/MySUbscription ID>/resourceGroups/MyresourceGroup/providers/Microsift.Net/LoadBalancer/MyLoadBalancer/LoadBalancingRules/MyLoadBalancingrule was not found.Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in same region ."
 Please suggest

```
Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name "MyLoadBalancer" -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" | Remove-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "BackendAddressPool02" | Set-AzLoadBalancer
```

Comment: Are you providing correct values? A backend address pool configuration must exist before you can delete it.

Comment: @jagrati Modi-AIS Am giving name inside of backend poo i.e ilb-Backend-VK1 for Remove-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig, Am I making any mistake there?

Comment: But in error you get resource id for load balancer rule.

Comment: I don't understand why it's getting..but am giving all correct values...There can be any issue with load balancer rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you did not show the complete error message, seems I can reproduce your issue.

[image]

The error was caused by your `Backend pool` referenced by the `Load balancing rule`, so to fix the issue, you need to use the command below to remove the rule first.

```
$loadbalancer = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name <LoadBalancer-name> -ResourceGroupName <group-name>
Remove-AzLoadBalancerRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $loadbalancer -Name <rule-name> | Set-AzLoadBalancer
```

Then run the command to remove the Backend pool, it works.

```
Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name "<LoadBalancer-name>" -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>" | Remove-AzLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "joyback1" | Set-AzLoadBalancer
```

[image]